# PHP encoding . what is this type

Tags: php

I have got a file with two line. below are lines:

```
<?php include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."\057\144\145f\151n\x65.\160\150p");
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/\x62\x73\145t.ph\160"); ?>
```

this is not look like encoding, if encoding what type of encoding this is and how to decode it (if possible). please tell anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a simple obfuscation technique. The characters are written in hexadecimal form (`\x00`), or octal form (`\000`). Have a look at this [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

```
<?php

  echo "\057\144\145f\151n\x65.\160\150p"; // it prints '/define.php'
  echo "/\x62\x73\145t.ph\160"; // it prints '/bset.php'

?>
```

To decode them, just look at this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/), for `\x00` look the Hx column, for `\000` values, the Oct one. For another method, (but printing the string it's the simplest thing to do...) you could also use the function `chr()`, to get the character representation:

```
echo chr(0x65); // print 'e', from value (hex) \x65
echo chr(0145); // still print 'e', from (oct) \145
```

Converting `\x00` and `\000` respectively to `0x00` and `0000`  is left as an exercise for you:)

Comment: how you decode that ? please give me idea

Comment: @user2498559 execute his script. (not yours)